# Firebase 2.0 functionality without Play services on the device

Tags: firebase, google-play-services

I cannot find out limitations of new firebase 2.0 features for non-google markets.

What will work as in Firebase 1.0,
What will work in compatibility mode (line analytics, wich will grow up service from dependency lib and will work even when there is no play services on the device) and what is disadvantages, what extra steps should be done for this to work,
And what will not work at all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firebase does not officially support Android devices without Google Play.  Some features such as Analytics and Realtime Database may work on those devices, but Firebase does not guarantee it.