# Would using the new Firebase as mBaaS for Android & iOS apps limit the use only to phones that support google services?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-play-services, mbaas

Considering that Google just announced a lot of good changes to Firebase recently and the stability that comes with "Google" in terms of future, I am inclined to make my decision and use Firebase for production but

1. My question is, would using the new Firebase as BaaS limit my application to only work on devices which support google services or not?
2. Is there any solution for that? If not yet, is there any information on whether google has any plan for solving this in the near future ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should mention that I have done quite a bit of search but has not been able to find a clear answer to my question. Just to clarify

Comment: Some Firebase features may work on devices without Google Play Services, others will not. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423767/firebase-2-0-functionality-without-play-services-on-the-device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup), you need a device running Google Play Services 2.9.1 or newer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong. I just read the documentation. Please check my updated answer. Firebase is actually part of the google play services. That's why we apply it in the gradle

Answer (score 0):

> 1. My question is, would using the new Firebase as BaaS limit my application to only work on devices which support google services or
>      not?

No. Google Play Services is only required for Android devices and nearly every device has them installed. (Except those crappy gumball machine phones but it's save to ignore them)

> 2. Is there any solution for that? If not yet, is there any information on whether google has any plan for solving this in the
>      near future ?

Since there is no problem there is no solution needed. Firebase is currently available for Android and iOS applications and has an API for Web Development as well if you wanna use the data on your own website.