# Firebase on an Android device without Google Services

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I understand that Firebase does not support android devices that do not have google services installed.
I'm trying to build a native android app on a Clover Till (https://docs.clover.com/). I need realtime database and authentication. The rest of the firebase features would be nice however I can get by with just the database and authentication.

It seems like realtime database is working but authentication is not.
Am I correct in saying that firebase auth needs google services to work in android?
If so, what are my options?
Could I build a hybrid app to get around this?
Thanks

Comment: firebase has a REST API, I suggest looking through that https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/user-auth.html

Comment: Aside from the option mentioned by @tyczj, there is no way to run Firebase Auth 3.x on devices without Google Play Services at the moment. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423767/firebase-2-0-functionality-without-play-services-on-the-device?rq=1. If you want to use the REST API, see this on how to [mint a custom token on your server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens).

Comment: Thanks guys, I had been looking at custom tokens earlier, but had presumed that my non-google-service client would not be able to call FirebaseAuth.signInWithCustomToken(token). Is that not the case? Or can that method work without google services?

Comment: I've authenticated using REST on Android, and am receiving localId, idToken etc. However, it seems that FirebaseDatabase is still making calls unauthenticated. Is there anyway I can authenticate FirebaseDatabase manually with the token? Or am I stuck making every call with REST rather than FirebaseDatabase?

Comment: Looking this : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/gcLE25p46e4

Comment: @AlanHaverty , were you able to resolve the issue or find a workaround. I am stuck with the exact same problem

Comment: @ArchitSinha No, we ended up not supporting devices without google play services unfortunately.