# Firebase analytics and crashlytics working with devices not having google play services

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics, crashlytics-android

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) for firebase, it is clear that firebase requires google play services.

We are targeting some devices without google play services. We have tried testing firebase crashlytics and analytics in those devices and the crash logs are perfectly uploaded to the firebase console. Are there any exceptions for some products of firebase which could run without google play services?

We want only analytics and crashlytics from firebase.

Comment: Some Firebase products may work without Google Play Services. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423767/firebase-2-0-functionality-without-play-services-on-the-device

Comment: Cheers..!! @FrankvanPuffelen . The Site has no answer and we are really not sure which services of firebase works without google services. Any more information on this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Unfortunately you don't want to build a product around a service that doesn't state unequivocally where and when it is supported.